# how to use call this argument with regular function?

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

I am trying to call divRepo element with forEach() Method but I am confused because of **this** argument. I am okay to use the **this** argument with the **arrow function**. But, I get an undefined text as output when I am using the **this** argument with **regular function**. is it possible to call the divRepo with **regular function**?
Thanks...

> **With Regular Function**

```js
    class UI {
      constructor() {
        this.divRepo = document.querySelector("#repos");
        
      }
    
      showUserRepositories(repos) {
        repos.forEach(function (repo) {

       console.log(this) //output : undefined

          this.divRepo.innerHTML = `
            <div class="mb-2 card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                <a href="${repo.html_url}" target = "_blank" id = "repoName" >${repo.name}</a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
        
                        </div>
            `;
        });
      }
    
      
    }
```

> **With Arrow Function**

```
class UI {
constructor() {
  this.divRepo = document.querySelector("#repos");
  
}

showUserRepositories(repos) {
  repos.forEach( (repo) => {
    console.log(this) // output : UI {divRepo: div#repos}
    this.divRepo.innerHTML = `
      <div class="mb-2 card-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-2">
                          <a href="${repo.html_url}" target = "_blank" id = "repoName" >${repo.name}</a>
                          </div>
                  </div>
  
                  </div>
      `;
  });
}
```

}

Comment: you could store `this` in `_this` or use `bind` on the function but what's the point? Just use an arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you're not ok using an arrow function since that was designed to address this type of problem. If you have to use a non arrow function for some reason, one option is to use the *second* argument to `forEach` which establishes the `this` context:

```
repos.forEach(function (repo) {
  // ...
}, this);
```

There are other alternatives such as capturing a reference to `this` in the closure:

```
const that = this;
repos.forEach(function (repo) {
  // ...
  console.log(that);
});
```

...or bind:

```
const processRepo = function (repo) {
  // ...
};
repos.forEach(processRepo.bind(this));
```

Comment: I am a little curious person, I was thinking about what is the other solutions ...Thanks Jacob